if else not working as expected in SASViya
i am new to SAS Viya and trying to write a if else statement but its not working as expecting.
%let qtr=%sysfunc(date(),qtr);

%if &qtr=1 %then 

%do;

%let qtr=4;

%else %do;

%let qtr=&qtr-1;

%end;

proc print &qtr;

Its printing the current quarter value of 2 instead of 1.

That code wouldn't print anything.  There are several errors.  Can you please update the question, to provide an example with code that runs without errors?

The issue has nothing to with IF or %IF.  If you want to perform integer arithmetic in macro code use %EVAL().  If you need to perform floating point arithmetic use %SYSEVALF().  If you want to manipulate dates then use INTNX() function.  You can call it in macro code by wrapping in %SYSFUNC() macro function.

If you want to find the previous qtr use the INTNX() function.
 %let today=%sysfunc(date());
 %let previous_qtr=%sysfunc(intnx(qtr,&today,-1),qtr.);


i had to use eval for doing the subtraction.. and it worked..
%let qtr=eval(&qtr-1);
